# Can you help me use Selenium to click Add To Cart button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however i cant seem to get Selenium to click the "Add To Cart" button using either find_element_by_class or find_element_by_XPATH. The problem is to check if the item is out of stock, and if it is out of stock then to refresh the webpage and restart the script. If the item is in stock then it should click "Add To Cart"

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL i am practicing on:

https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html

And this is my current code for the clicking:

```
# Selenium Tutorial #1

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")

#search = driver.find_element_by_id(ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifyBtn)

link = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
link.click

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    element.click()
except Exception:
    pass

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "email-desktop"))
    )
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF hZIOeU Button-jyKNMA GZkwS")
    link.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass multiple classes to `find_element_by_class_name`. Instead use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` or `xpath`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Python Scripts\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")

#search = driver.find_element_by_id(ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifyBtn)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    element.click()
except Exception:
    pass

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "email-desktop"))
    )
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.GZkwS")
```

Next, if you would call `button.is_displayed()` it will return `False`, because it is a hidden element. This means you cannot interact with it using `button.click()`. Instead, you can use javascript to click the button.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: Thankyou! That worked perfectly. I am having some trouble replicating it on the next page though with the "Go to checkout" button.

I am using this code
```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Go to Checkout")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```